# Конвертация 16-битного файл в 8-битный Python

Tags: python, scipy, wav

Добрый вечер, стоит задача конвертировать извлеченную из 16 битного Wav файла data  в 8 битную, затем записать ее в .bin файл , а затем в декодоре извлечь и заного создать wav файл, для сравнения. Как правильно конвертировать/деконверитровать из 16 в 8 бит?

Сам конвертор(:

```
(_, data) = scipy.io.wavfile.read('Audio_track.wav')

def bit_8(data):

   new_data=np.uint8(data)

   with open('J:\PCharmPrj\encoded8bit.bin','wb') as wav:
    pickle.dump(new_data, wav)
    wav.close()
```

Декодер:

```
def bit_8():

wav = open('J:\PCharmPrj\encoded8bit.bin', 'rb')
data_8bit = pickle.load(wav)

new_data=np.uint16(data_8bit) - пробовал и с ней и без нее

scipy.io.wavfile.write('J:\PCharmPrj\decoded8bit.wav',44100,new_data)
```

На выходе дикий шум , без каких либо намеков на оригинальный трек. Спасибо за подсказку заранее.

Comment: related: [converter wave 24 bit to 16 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39788464/4279)

Comment: Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить, конвертируя 16-бит wav в 8-бит?

Comment: Чисто учебная задача

Comment: какую тему вы хотите выучить? Какую библиотеку использовать, чтобы выполнить преобразование или как руками алгоритм написать?

Comment: В чем собственно мой вопрос и есть, какой библиотекой выполнить приеобразование даты 16 битного трека в 8 битную  для записи в bin файл и потом для декодирования ее обратно в wav

Comment: в первом комментарии ссылка на ответ, в котором показано как soundfile использовать. Для вашего случая, попробуйте PCM_S8 subtype

Comment: pickle предназначен для записи данных в файл, чтобы их смог потом прочитать python (с помощью того же pickle). Но если записать через него, например, байтовый массив (bytes), то кроме самого массива запишутся дополнительные данные для чтения с помощью pickle. В случае байтового массива его нужно писать напрямую через write. В случае WAV нужно еще дописать в начало заголовок файла. Тут ничего сложного, если покопаться. Но pickle это явно не то что вам нужно.